# Общее свойство у нескольких классов

Tags: unity3d

Доброго времени суток!
У меня есть массив `Transform[]` в котором находятся объекты разных классов, например, 2 объекта класса `Animal`, 2 объекта класса `Beetle` и 3 объекта класса `Human`.

Мне нужно из этого массива `Transform[]` получить только объекты-`Animal` и объекты-`Beetle` .

Как это лучше сделать, не проверяя наличие компонента (`obj.GetComponent<Animal>() != null && obj.GetComponent<Beetle >() != null`)?

Нужно для них завести какое-то общее свойство, но как это сделать? И можно ли как-то универсально менять значение этого свойства, а не также, как через получения компонента.

Comment: Если вы точно знаете, что такие объекты есть, то проверку можно и не делать

Comment: Никита Васильченко, мне нужно проверить не наличие этих объектов, а получить их для дальнейших действий с ними. Хотя и для проверки наличия, тоже нужно будет это общее свойство, чтобы отсеять ненужные объекты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нужно для них завести какое-то общее свойство, но как это сделать?

Создайте, например базовый абстрактный класс для ваших объектов, c общим свойством, которое будете перегружать нужным вам образом в дочерних классах. Например:

```
public abstract class Creature : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool IsHumanoid { get; } 
}
```

И предположите, что у классов `Beetle` и `Animal`  это свойство, к примеру `false`, а у `Human` оно `true`.
Тогда у вас появится несколько вариантов решения:

1. У каждого элемента массива типа `Transform[]`, получать компонент, `Creature` и смотреть нужное свойство. Также вынести нужные действия для классов в виртуальный метод и работать в коде с базовым типом `Creature`, вместо конкретного типа.
2. Вместо массива типа `Transform[]`, хранить массив типа `Creature[]` и работать с базовым классом.
3. Вместо свойства типа `bool`, завести свойство типа `enum` например: `public enum CreatureType { Beetle, Animal, Human }`. И приводить базовы тип `Creature`, исходя из значения этого свойства к нужному вам типу. Например:

   ```
   Beetle myBeetle;
   Creature creature = myArray[0];
   if(creature.CrType == CreatureType.Beetle)
       myBeetle = (Beetle)creature;
   ```

И аналогично для классов `Human`и `Animal`